# Are joke answers very low quality?

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

As we get into the more public realm, I see the potential for people posting pseudo-answers that are meant to be humorous more than helpful, like [this one](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/2146/78), becoming more commonplace. As I'd hate for Lifehacks to become full of answers like these, I don't think they should be encouraged, perhaps even disallowed.

Should we flag answers like these as very low quality?

Comment: Must... resist... urge to add joke answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers in this area are in the grey area and should be handled on a case to case basis.

In any case, if you think the answer is not a serious one or is plain wrong, feel free to  **downvote it**. This shows both the user and the community that answers like it are not preferable. The user may even remove it them self at that point.

As for **flagging** it as low quality, this **should only be done in cases where it is more joke that informative (i.e. not posted in good faith)**. Sometimes silly sounding answers [are legitimate](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/1763/78), though perhaps not the best solution or a favorable one. To know the difference, some research will have to be done. Hopefully the answer is a good one and thus *provide the research in the answer itself*, but more often than not they won't. If they don't, that's more reason why you could choose to downvote.

Comment: But there IS a difference between a "silly sounding" answer (correct or incorrect) and a joke answer or one posted simple to elicit a reaction. Generally if an answer is more joke that informative (i.e. not posted in good faith), it is okay (and recommended) to remove it. But you are correct; if a question is simply incorrect (or implausible), voting is the correct course of action. Users should not generally flag an answer because they do not agree with the information it contains.

Comment: Flags should always be saved for unsalvageable garbage. If the post doesn't qualify as that, you can downvote and delete-vote, don't flag. Some joke answers could easily be edited into something useful.